# Python webbrowser module isn't working correctly

Tags: python

I'm creating this automation script in python that uses a dictionary to open a browser and when using webbrowser module to open a parsed dictionary, I keep getting a key error. Here is the code:

```
import webbrowser, sys, requests
ptcl = 'https://'
tail = '.com/'
context_dict =
    {
        'fb': ptcl + 'facebook' + tail,
        'ig': ptcl + 'instagram' + tail,
        'google': ptcl + 'google' + tail,
        'kat': ptcl + 'kat.cr',
        'mail': ptcl + 'gmail' + tail,
        'utube': ptcl + 'youtube' + tail,       
        }


def open_page(page):
    webbrowser.open(context_dict[page])
def get_args():
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        for i in sys.argv[1:]:
            page = context_dict[i.replace(',', '')]
            open_page(page)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_args()
```

Here is an example of when trying to access fb from the cmd
[sample fb run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wor6V.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You lookup twice:

```
page = context_dict[i.replace(',', '')]
```

then

```
webbrowser.open(context_dict[page])
```

Remove one of the lookups.

I would suggest:

```
def get_args():
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        for i in sys.argv[1:]:
            key = i.replace(',', '')
            open_page(key)
```

Comment: Thanks, I was redundant